# Installing Developer Version of scikit-learn under anaconda

Tags: python, scikit-learn, anaconda, install.packages

I'm trying to install the developer package of scikit in anaconda (python 2.7). I cloned the git repo according to the doc:

http://scikit-learn.org/stable/developers/contributing.html#git-repo

but I don't see how i can add it to the package manager.

Please let me know how to manage packages in this case properly since i'm still pretty new to python and anaconda.

In this case creating a new environment would make sense wouldn't it?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to *register* the development version of scikit-learn you have two alternative options:

1) If you plan yo modify it and make changes to that version, then add the cloned directory to the PYTHONPATH environment variable so you can import and use it from other projects. How to do that depends on your OS.

2) just install it doing `python setup.py install` inside the cloned folder.

Comment: thanks for you reply, it should work once i got the error: 'unable to find vcvarsall.bat' sorted